# Array to string conversion Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy haciendo un sistema en donde se cargan ciertos registros en la base de datos mediante un csv.. pero para subirlos el sistema compara si los 
usuarios existen dentro de la base de datos..

este es mi controlador

```
public function puntosImport(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('puntos')){
        $path = $request->file('puntos')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();
        $users = User::all();
        $mytime= Carbon::now('America/Asuncion');
        if($data->count()){
            foreach ($users as $key => $u) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    if ($u->USUARIO == $value->username) {

                        $total_positivo = 
                            intval($value->disc_puntualidad_pos) + 
                            intval($value->productividad_pos + intval($value->gestion_pos) + 
                            intval($value->meritos_taller_curso) + intval($value->merito_univ) + 
                            intval($value->merito_espec) + intval($value->be_disc_puntualidad) + 
                            intval($value->be_disc_ausencia) + intval($value->be_disc_apercib) + 
                            intval($value->be_prod_fluor) + intval($value->be_prod_fluor_verde) + 
                            intval($value->be_prod_verde) + intval($value->be_gestion_excelente) + 
                            intval($value->be_gestion_exc_buena) + intval($value->be_gestion_buena));
                        // var_dump($total_positivo); die;
                        $puntos_list[] = [
                            'username' => $value->username, 
                            'first_name' => $value->first_name, 
                            'last_name' => $value->last_name,
                            'disc_puntualidad_pos' => $value->disc_puntualidad_pos,
                            'disc_puntualidad_neg' => $value->disc_puntualidad_neg,
                            'disc_marcacion_neg' => $value->disc_marcacion_neg,
                            'disc_ausencia_neg' => $value->disc_ausencia_neg,
                            'disc_apercibimiento_neg' => $value->disc_apercibimiento_neg,
                            'disc_suspension_neg' => $value->disc_suspension_neg,
                            'productividad_pos' => $value->productividad_pos,
                            'productividad_neg' => $value->productividad_neg,
                            'gestion_pos' => $value->gestion_pos,
                            'gestion_neg' => $value->gestion_neg,
                            'meritos_taller_curso' => $value->meritos_taller_curso,
                            'merito_univ' => $value->merito_univ,
                            'merito_espec' => $value->merito_espec,
                            'be_disc_puntualidad' => $value->be_disc_puntualidad,
                            'be_disc_ausencia' => $value->be_disc_ausencia,
                            'be_disc_apercib' => $value->be_disc_apercib,
                            'be_prod_fluor' => $value->be_prod_fluor,
                            'be_prod_fluor_verde' => $value->be_prod_fluor_verde,
                            'be_prod_verde' => $value->be_prod_verde,
                            'be_gestion_excelente' => $value->be_gestion_excelente,
                            'be_gestion_exc_buena' => $value->be_gestion_exc_buena,
                            'be_gestion_buena' => $value->be_gestion_buena,
                            'total_puntos_positivos' => $total_positivo,
                            'user_id' => $u->id,
                            'created_at' => $value->created_at
                        ];
                    } else {
                        $puntos_no[] = [
                            'username' => $value->username, 
                            'first_name' => $value->first_name, 
                            'last_name' => $value->last_name
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!empty($puntos_list)){
                Punto::insert($puntos_list);
                \Session::flash('success','Archivo importado con exito!.');
            }
            if(!empty($puntos_no)){

                \Session::flash('infor','Algunos usuarios no fueron agregados por que no existe en la base de datos!.'. array($puntos_no));
            }
        }
    }else{
        \Session::flash('warnning','Error al subir archivo');
    }
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

y esta es mi vista..

```
<div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
            @if (Session::has('infor'))
               <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('info') }}
           </div>
            @endif
            @if (Session::has('success'))
               <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>
            @elseif (Session::has('warnning'))
                <div class="alert alert-warnning">{{ Session::get('warnning') }}</div>
            @endif
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es capturar los usuarios que no están en la base de datos en un array llamado $puntos_no y le tiro un mensaje diciendo que algunos usuarios no se agregaron... Lo que me gustaría saber es como puedo hacer para que en el mensaje se muestre el nombre de los usuarios que no fueron agregados a la base de datos...

Comment: Puedes mandar el arreglo al view y recorrer el arreglo con un foreach para que muestres los nombres de todos los usuarios que no fueron agregados.

Comment: intente hacer eso enviandolo con un compact pero no me funciono... lo puse dentro del if del blade y me salia que la variable no estaba definida..

Comment: Pero agrégalo a `Session::flash('puntos_no', $puntos_no)` y dentro del if `@if (Session::has('infor'))
               <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('info') }}
           </div> <ul>@foreach(Session::get('puntos_no') as $user)<li>{{ $user->username }}</li> @endforeach </ul>
            @endif`